# How to replicate only one data type 'n' times in list using rep()

Tags: r

```
fred <- list(num = c(1:10) , name = "hello")
```

How to repeat `num` type 5 times and `name` type 10 times in lists using `rep()`?

Comment: Try something.  You know what function to use.  It's easy.

Comment: Check `?rep` and try the examples there.

Comment: `lookup = c(num = 5, name = 10);
lapply(names(fred), function(x) rep(fred[[x]], each = lookup[x]))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `mapply` which applies the function to the elements of fred and the times vector.

```
mapply(function(x, y) rep(x, times=y), fred, c(5, 10))
$num
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[30] 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$name
 [1] "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello"
```

The list is replicated simply using

```
rep(fred, c(5,10))
```